# Avoid asm__dyld__dyld_start on run when in debug window

Tags: xcode

Whenever I start my app and I have my view setup to see the code and the console in the debug view (in a all-in-one setup) my source view get switched to asm code for asm__dyld__dyld_start.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the setting in Run->Debugger Display to "Source Only" instead of "Dissasembly Only".

Comment: What if you continue execution? Is the debugger stopping at program startup (in asm code, since it's not your source)? Perhaps a GDB setting?

Comment: it doesn't stop, it just shows me the asm, if i switch to code view and back to debug view, the source code from code view shows back in debug view.

Comment: You may want to try the xcode-users list hosted by Apple: http://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/xcode-users